# Applescript to type text, followed by a modifier key combo?

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I want to use TextExpander to activate when I type the specific text "attached", and have the AppleScript type out the word "attached" (since TextExpander will remove it), and then invoke the keystroke Control-Z

I can get each to work individually, but not together. Here is the code I am using based off of code I found [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13886530&postcount=1):

```
    tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "attached"
    keystroke "z" using control down
    end tell
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the TextExpander application name and process name is so I will guess what it is.

```
activate application "TextExpander"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "TextExpander"
            keystroke "attached"
            delay 0.5
            keystroke "z" using {command down}
        end tell
    end tell
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the "attached" text does not type out. The delay and the Ctrl-Z actions work fine.

Comment: If the edited version does not work, you may need to save it as an app, change the plist so it runs in the background and remove the tell process..

Answer (score 0):

TextExpander has its own script-ability.

Links:

- [AppleScripting TextExpander - Blog](http://smilesoftware.com/blog/entry/applescripting-textexpander)
- [AppleScripting TextExpander Details](http://www.smilesoftware.com/help/TextExpander/scriptingte.html)

Example:

```
tell application "Alfred 2"
    search ""
    tell application "TextExpander"
        expand abbreviation ";drmt"
    end tell
end tell
```